# add header to columns from list text file awk

Tags: linux, shell, awk

I have a very large text file with hundreds of columns. I want to add a header to every column from an independent text file containing a list.

My large file looks like this:

```
largefile.txt
chrom start end 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 etc
chrom start end 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 etc
chrom start end 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 etc
```

my list of headers:

```
headers.txt
h1
h2
h3
```

wanted output:

```
output.txt
                h1 h2 h3 h4 h5 h6 h7 etc..
chrom start end 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 etc
chrom start end 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 etc
chrom start end 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 etc
```

Comment: so headers should be added starting from the 4th field, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{h=h OFS $0; next} FNR==1{print OFS OFS h} 1' head large | column -s ' ' -t
                   h1  h2  h3
chrom  start  end  0   1   0   1  0  0  0  etc
chrom  start  end  0   0   0   0  1  1  1  etc
chrom  start  end  0   0   0   1  1  1  1  etc
```

or if you prefer:

```
$ awk -v OFS='\t' 'NR==FNR{h=h OFS $0; next} FNR==1{print OFS OFS h} {$1=$1}1' head large
                        h1      h2      h3
chrom   start   end     0       1       0       1       0       0       0       etc
chrom   start   end     0       0       0       0       1       1       1       etc
chrom   start   end     0       0       0       1       1       1       1       etc
```

Comment: yes, I also ended up with similar `awk 'NR==FNR{l=l FS $1; next}FNR==1{ printf("%s%s%s%s\n", FS,FS,FS,l); print}1' headers.txt  largefile.txt`

Comment: Never use the letter `l` as a variable name as it looks far too much like the number `1` (completely indistinguishable in some fonts)  and so obfuscates your code (e.g. at a glance we can't tell if `FNR==1` is testing for FNR equal to the string you created and stored in the variable `l` or to the number `1`, and is that a test for `l` or `1` at the end, etc...?). I spent 3 hours helping someone debug a script once where the error turned out to be that their typing teacher had told them to use `l` instead of `1` as its faster to type and looks the same - Grrrr...

Comment: I didn't post it, so, no fear

Comment: Oh nice move that `OFS` in the `NR==FNR{}`. Why didn't I think of that. ^

Comment: thanks @EdMorton that worked perfectly for my data. Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

Well, here's one. `OFS` is tab for eye candy. From the OP I concluded that the headers should start from the fourth field, hence `+3`s in the code.

```
$ awk -v OFS="\t" '               # tab OFS
NR==FNR { a[NR]=$1; n=NR; next }  # has headers
FNR==1  {                         # print headers in the beginning of 2nd file
    $1=$1                         # rebuild record for tabs
    b=$0                          # buffer record
    $0=""                         # clear record
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)             # spread head to fields
        $(i+3)=a[i]
    print $0 ORS b                # output head and buffered first record
}
{ $1=$1 }1' head data             # implicit print with record rebuild
                        h1      h2      h3
chrom   start   end     0       1       0       1       0       0       0       etc
chrom   start   end     0       0       0       0       1       1       1       etc
chrom   start   end     0       0       0       1       1       1       1       etc
```

Then again, this would also do the trick:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{h=h (NR==1?"":OFS) $0;next}FNR==1{print OFS OFS OFS h}1' head date
   h1 h2 h3
chrom start end 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 etc
chrom start end 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 etc
chrom start end 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 etc
```

Answer (score 0):

Use paste to pivot the headers into a single line and then cat them together with the main file (`-` instead of a file name means stdin to cat):

```
$ paste -s -d' ' headers.txt | cat - largefile.txt
```

If you really need the headers to line up as in your example output you can preprocess (either manually or with a command) the headers file, or you can finish with sed (for just one option) as below:

```
$ paste -s -d' ' headers.txt | cat - largefile.txt | sed '1 s/^/                /'
                h1 h2 h3
chrom start end 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 etc
chrom start end 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 etc
chrom start end 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 etc
```